Desktop icon not showing in application menu
On my Kubuntu Laptop, I installed an AppImage and created a .desktop file for it. Now when I start the application the icon is shown in the window bar but not when searching for the application in the application menu. Here are some informations about the icon file I'm using:
PNG image data, 100 x 100, 8-bit/color RGBA, non-interlaced



I don't think I did anything wrong with the icon path, otherwise the icon wouldn't be displayed in the first image.
This is the icon that I'm using

Thanks for your help.

What do you see if you right click the Application launcher entry, select "edit application" - is there an icon displayed? If not, select it there too.

@cipricus Nice that worked! Thank you!

I've posted as answer so you can mark it solved.

Rright click the Application launcher entry, select "edit application" - if there's no icon displayed, select one there.


